# Mysql LOAD XML with column names containing umlauts

Tags: mysql, xml, linux

I'm trying to load data from external XML files into mysql. Everything works, sort of, but when the external XML file defines data with labels containing umlauts, I get no data. I've tried creating my database with different character sets etc. Like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbValnatt
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Or this:

```
CREATE DATABASE dbValnatt
 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1
 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

But no love... The external XML is called `valnatt_00R.xml` and can be found in [this ZIP archive](https://data.val.se/val/val2014/valnatt/valnatt.zip). The first few lines below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/html"?>
<!DOCTYPE VAL PUBLIC "-//Valmyndigheten//DTD Valresultat parti nation 1.6//SV" "http://www.val.se/dtd/resultat/parti_nation_1_6.dtd">
<VAL TILLFÄLLE="Allmänna val 14 september 2014" FILNAMN="valnatt_00R.xml" RAPPORTERING="VALNATTSRAPPORTERING" VALTYP="Riksdagsval" VALDAG="20140914" VALDAG_FGVAL="20100919" TID_RAPPORT="20141022134945">
  <PARTI FÖRKORTNING="M" BETECKNING="Moderaterna" FÄRG="#66BEE6" />
  <PARTI FÖRKORTNING="SD" BETECKNING="Sverigedemokraterna" FÄRG="#4E83A3" />
  <PARTI FÖRKORTNING="S" BETECKNING="Arbetarepartiet-Socialdemokraterna" FÄRG="#FF0000" />
  <PARTI FÖRKORTNING="FP" BETECKNING="Folkpartiet liberalerna" FÄRG="#3399FF" />
  <PARTI FÖRKORTNING="C" BETECKNING="Centerpartiet" FÄRG="#63A91D" />
  <PARTI FÖRKORTNING="V" BETECKNING="Vänsterpartiet" FÄRG="#C40000" />
  <PARTI FÖRKORTNING="FI" BETECKNING="Feministiskt initiativ" FÄRG="#cd0067" />
  <PARTI FÖRKORTNING="MP" BETECKNING="Miljöpartiet de gröna" FÄRG="#008000" />
  <PARTI FÖRKORTNING="KD" BETECKNING="Kristdemokraterna" FÄRG="#1B5CB1" />
  <PARTI FÖRKORTNING="ÖVR" BETECKNING="Övriga partier" FÄRG="#999999" />
  <PARTI FÖRKORTNING="BLANK" BETECKNING="Ogiltiga röster - blanka" FÄRG="#cc99ff" />
  <PARTI FÖRKORTNING="OG" BETECKNING="Ogiltiga röster - övriga" FÄRG="#003300" />
```

And I try to load it with this SQL script:

```
CREATE TABLE tblTest2(
 id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 FÖRKORTNING VARCHAR(16) NULL, 
 BETECKNING VARCHAR(16) NULL,
 FÄRG VARCHAR(16) NULL
)
 ENGINE MyISAM
 COMMENT '';

LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'valnatt_00R.xml'
 INTO TABLE tblTest2
 ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<PARTI>';
```

But a `SELECT * FROM tblTest2;` returns:

```
id, FÖRKORTNING,BETECKNING,       FÄRG
1,  NULL,       Moderaterna,      NULL
2,  NULL,       Sverigedemokrate, NULL
3,  NULL,       Arbetarepartiet-, NULL
4,  NULL,       Folkpartiet libe, NULL
5,  NULL,       Centerpartiet,    NULL
6,  NULL,       Vänsterpartiet,   NULL
7,  NULL,       Feministiskt ini, NULL
8,  NULL,       Miljöpartiet de,  NULL
9,  NULL,       Kristdemokratern, NULL
10, NULL,       Övriga partier,   NULL
11, NULL,       Ogiltiga röster,  NULL
12, NULL,       Ogiltiga röster,  NULL
```

The column `BETECKNING` gets data, but not `FÄRG` and `FÖRKORTNING`. Hence the names containing umlauts.

For the record:

- Host: Linux tatooine 4.9.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u1
  (2017-12-23) x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Database: Server version:
  10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.1

A selection of my database variables:

```
character_set_client        utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database      latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results       utf8
character_set_server        latin1
character_set_system        utf8
character_sets_dir          /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
collation_connection        utf8_general_ci
collation_database          latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server            latin1_swedish_ci
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try setting character_set_database  to utf16_general_ci

Comment: Tried creating the database like this:

    CREATE DATABASE db
     CHARACTER SET utf16
    COLLATE utf16_general_ci;

Still NULL for the columns with umlauts in their names. The other columns went bonkers with chinese chars...